# python regex findall and multiline

Tags: python, regex

python 2.6.8

```
s= '''
foo 
bar
baz
'''
>>>re.findall(r'^\S*',s,re.MULTILINE)
['', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', '']
>>>ptrn = re.compile(r'^\S*',re.MULTILINE)
>>>ptrn.findall(s)
['', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', '']
>>>ptrn.findall(s,re.MULTILINE)
['baz', '']
```

Why is there a difference between using MULTILINE flag in findall?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When calling the `findall()` method on a regex object, the second parameter is not the `flags` argument (because that has already been used when compiling the regex) but the `pos` argument, telling the regex engine at which point in the string to start matching.

`re.MULTILINE` is just an integer (that happens to be `8`).

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall).

Comment: never bothered to check if re.MULTILINE was an object or int

Answer (score 11):

Because the `findall` method of the compiled object `ptrn` doesn't take the MULTILINE parameter. It takes a `position` argument.

See here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall

The MULTILINE specifier is only used when you call `re.compile()` The resulting `ptrn` object already 'knows' that it is `MULTILINE`.