# Why does python re.findall() for the same regex produce different results for two equivalent input strings?

Tags: python, regex

Why is `re.findall()` only showing a *single* match for the first expression (`ex1`) but *two matches* for the second expression (`ex2`). I expected two matches for both cases because they appear to be equivalent for this case.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

# first expression (no leading new line)
ex1 = '''\
ipv4: {{ var1 }}
timestamp: {{ var2 }}
'''

# second expression, prepended '#\n'
ex2 = '#\n' + ex1

re1 = re.compile(r'{{\s*.+\s*}}')

# Why are they different?
print(re1.findall(ex1, re.M))  # 1 match
print(re1.findall(ex2, re.M))  # 2 matches
#assert re1.findall(ex1, re.M) == re1.findall(ex2, re.M)
```

Here is the output. It is the same for python2 and python3:

```
['{{ var2 }}']
['{{ var1 }}', '{{ var2 }}']
```

Comment: Apparently prepending the new line did something.

Comment: Scratch that, it's the hash.

Comment: Yup, do you have any idea why? I didn't see anything in the docs that would explain it.

Comment: Do not use `re.M`. It is a common problem. The argument expected there is not the flag.

Comment: Nope. I suggest you amend your question for specificity - why does adding a `#` at the beginning of a string check `re.findall` results, or something similar - without the newline.

Comment: Thank you Wictor, you solved it. I will post the answer below.

Comment: And I will close as a dupe once I find a good one.

Comment: Closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958728/python-regex-findall-and-multiline. It is a known problem. Same thing with `re.sub` - [Python re.sub with a flag does not replace all occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581/python-re-sub-with-a-flag-does-not-replace-all-occurrences).

Comment: What is "funny" is that `re.M` is totally redundant for this `{{\s*.+\s*}}` pattern since it has no `^` or `$` anchors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `re.M` incorrectly, this is the corrected code. Many thanks to [@Wictor][1] for pointing this out. Also, a number of others pointed out that `re.M` is not needed at all. Thank you all.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

ex1 = '''\
ipv4: {{ var1 }}
timestamp: {{ var2 }}
'''

ex2 = '#\n' + ex1

re1 = re.compile(r'{{\s*.+\s*}}')
print(re1.findall(ex1))  # 2 matches
print(re1.findall(ex2))  # 2 matches
assert re1.findall(ex1, re.M) == re1.findall(ex2, re.M)
```

Output:

```
['{{ var1 }}', '{{ var2 }}']
['{{ var1 }}', '{{ var2 }}']
```

Comment: @usr2564301 `re.M` redefines what `^` and `$` match and does not change `.` begavior. `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` makes `.` match any char.